# How to hide status bar after calling UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

I want to hide the status bar after calling UIImagePickerController on iOS 10.2.

There are several questions with answers that don't work for Swift 3.0.

The suggested answers are:

- extend UINavigationController to override preferStatusBarHidden, because UIImagePickerController is a subclass of UINavigationController.

So I tried:

```
extension UINavigationController{
    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }
}
```

- extend UIImagePickerController to override prefersStatusBarHidden.

So I tried:

```
extension UIImagePickerController{
    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }
}
```

- create and use a subclass of UIImagePicker

So I tried:

```
class MyImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController{
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }
}
```

None of the above solutions work for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The status bar can be permanently hidden with the following extension to `UIImagePickerController` :

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    open override var childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

This is working for Swift 3, on iOS 10.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the delegate method method of `UINavigationControllerDelegate` like below.

```
class PersonalInfoVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate{
```

**Adding the delegate and hide the status bar in it.**

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool){
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}
```

Comment: UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true was depricated from iOS 9.0. Can you update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

None of those answers worked for me on iOS 13. I had to set this flag on the presenting view controller before presenting the image picker:

`viewController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = YES;
[viewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

The status bar can be hidden and show when presenting view controller UIImagePickerController **swift 4+**

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
        statusBar.isHidden =  true
    }
})

picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
        statusBar.isHidden =  false
    }
})
```