# UIImagePickerController not properly cropping selected image

Tags: swift4, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a simple standard image-picker that works fine except that when I use the editor function the image is shifted above the square crop frame.  When I select the image or resize the image then accept it the cropped image has about 20 or so pixels of image above what the crop frame and about 40 pixels hacked off the bottom.  Below is the code.  Because a picture is worth a thousand words I have included two screen shots to show what it looks like in the edit mode and what I get back.  I would appreciate any suggestions code wise or setup wise that allow the editor to crop the picture accurately.

```
import UIKit
```

class ImagePickerVC: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnPickImage: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnCancel: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var btnSave: UIBarButtonItem!

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupNavBarAppearance(control: self)

    imagePicker.delegate = self

    myImage.image = myUserProfile.avatar
}
@IBAction func btnCancel(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func btnPickImage(_ sender: Any) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {
    myUserProfile.avatar = myImage.image!
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}

extension ImagePickerVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,       UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        myImage.image = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}
```

[image: image picker editor mode]

[image: the picture returned]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Status Bar is messing it up.

Adding the following extension worked to make the `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` correctly crop the image.

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    open override var childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

This extension hides the status bar in `UIImagePickerController` which looks a little weird but the result is all that matters.

I got it from [Swift 3.0 - how to hide status bar after calling UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456270/swift-3-0-how-to-hide-status-bar-after-calling-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: Black bar appears on top for me after doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks siefix!  This works perfectly.

Swift 4.2

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    open override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```